# Integrating Wordpress and Custom URL Rewrites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using Wordpress 3.4.1 with permalinks turned on.  In my .htaccess, I have the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

I also want to set up a custom rewrite (NOT a redirect) so that when a user goes to this URL:

http://example.com/about/video-center/youtubeID/title-slug/

It gets internally rewritten as:

http://example.com/about/video-center/

Right now, the first URL 404s.

---

I tried adding this rule to my .htaccess after the `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteRule ^about/video-center/(.+)$ /about/video-center/ [NC,L]
```

Which does nothing (I still get a 404).  If I add a `R` to the flags, then it redirects and /about/video-center/ loads just fine, which leads me to believe the rule is matching and rewriting appropriately.

---

My theory is that the rewrite works fine... but when WP's rewrite rules take effect, any custom rewrite rules I have are overridden -- that even though it's rewriting internally, WP is still trying to handle the URL that's in the address bar.

I don't know how to get around this and make my custom rewrites work with Wordpress.

Now, I realize it might not be possible to achieve the result I want from .htaccess alone, and that a plugin, or some custom code in my Theme's functions.php might be needed to solve this problem.  I'm open to whatever solution gets this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent too much time trying to find a solution for this, I'm just going to use hashes instead:

http://example.com/about/video-center/#youtubeID/title-slug/

Comment: If anyone happens to find a solution that solves this problem, I'll change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) looks promising. (From WP's docs) Check out the first example there - You can probably skip adding a query var, since the rewrite you're looking for seems simpler.

However, what happens to the ID / url-slug? That info is no longer needed?

Comment: The ID/Slug part of the URL gets used by Javascript in the browser. For the video section I want to use History.js to push states to the browser instead of reloading the page - but I want to allow users to permalink to a particular 'page', following the structure above - and I'm trying to do this without a query string or hash.  The first example from that link redirects to /about/video-center/ which is not what I want.